# How to use curly braces in a shell (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glob, brace-expansion

I'm currently trying to reproduce basic shell behaviours, and more specifically globbing behaviours.
I was testing commands with curly braces in it and found this behaviour that I don't understand.
First, the content of the directory I'm working in is the following :

`1abc  2abc  3abc  abc1  abc2  abc3`

Then, I typed the following command : `ls {[1-3],[a-c]}*`, and it returned me all the files above as expected.

And finally, I tried this command : `ls {{,[1-3]},[a-c]}*`, which as you can see, has imbricated curly braces. Now what I don't understand is the return of this command, because it gave me this : `1abc  1abc  2abc  2abc  3abc  3abc  abc1  abc1  abc2  abc2  abc3  abc3`

As you can see, all the files were returned two times, and I can't figure out how the shell is interpreting this.

I hope my explanation was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `{{,[1-3]},[a-c]}*` is an expression interpreted as [brace expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#BRACEEXPREF) that consists of the following patterns:

- "emptiness" (`{,`),
- `[1-3]`, and
- `[a-c]`.

The [`*`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#ASTERISKREF) character (meaning "every filename in the given directory") is applied for each of them:

```
*       => 1abc  2abc  3abc  abc1  abc2  abc3
[1-3]*  => 1abc  2abc  3abc
[a-c]*  => abc1  abc2  abc3
```

The fact that you have nested the expressions doesn't change the meaning that it is *just a list of the three patterns*. The same effect could be achieved with a simpler expression like `{,[1-3],[a-c]}*`, or another "list of lists" like `{,{[1-3],[a-c]}}*`.

If you pass the expression to `echo`, it will print all the characters from the lines above, one after another:

```
$ echo {{,[1-3]},[a-c]}*
1abc 2abc 3abc abc1 abc2 abc3 1abc 2abc 3abc abc1 abc2 abc3
```

But `ls` sorts the entries alphabetically by default:

```
$ ls {{,[1-3]},[a-c]}*
1abc  1abc  2abc  2abc  3abc  3abc  abc1  abc1  abc2  abc2  abc3  abc3
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for this explanation, it was really clear and I understand it now !

Answer (score 3):

Bash expands

```
{{,[1-3]},[a-c]}*
```

in first step (brace-expansion) to

```
* [1-3]* [a-c]*
```

In second step (globbing) bash expands `*` to all files **and** `[1-3]*` to all files starting with `1`,`2` or `3` **and** expands `[a-c]*` to all files starting with `a`, `b` or `c`.